# JNI method: formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, android, c++, string, java-native-interface

I'm trying to emend a JNI function that takes a string argument from the java layer.

Initially, the java code from the .java file was:

```
callJNIMethod();
```

I'm trying to change it so that I can give it a string, like this:

```
String arg = "abcd";
callJNIMethod(arg);
```

In my JNI code, this is what the function previously looked like:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_file_app_Activity_callJNIMethod(
JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz){

//use the string
}
```

This is what I changed it to (in the wrapper .cpp file and the header .h file):

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_file_app_Activity_callJNIMethod(
JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring str);
```

I'm getting an error that the method callJNIMethod cannot be applied to the given types.

```
required: no arguments
found: java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You must have `native boolean  callJNIMethod();` declaration somewhere in your java code - add the new parameter to it as well.

Comment: Ah yes, totally forgot about that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went astray by editing the .h file. Changes to native methods should begin in your Java source.

The .h file should be generated by `javah` from the compiled .class file. You can set up your build system to re-run `javah` with each build. That way you'll see right away if the native method implementations no longer match the native declarations in your Java source.